# Why is not the change of values ​made in the two arrays? just do the first

Tags: python, numpy

I have a three-dimensional array of 9x9x9 seen as 27 cubes of 3x3x3. After identifying two "cubes" of 3x3x3 with "id's" from 0 to 26 I want to change the values ​​of the two "cubes". When I do it, I only change the values ​​of the first cube (only the first line does)

Why does not python make the second change?

```py
mat = np.arange(729).reshape(9,9,9)

idO = int(input('Enter first id \n'))
idD = int(input('Enter second id \n'))


def limites(id):
    x=id%3
    y=(id%9)//3
    z=id//9

    limites = np.array([z,y,x])
    return limites

def mover(limitesA, limitesB):
    tempA = mat[limitesA[0]*3:(limitesA[0]*3)+3, limitesA[1]*3:(limitesA[1]*3)+3, limitesA[2]*3:(limitesA[2]*3)+3]
    print(tempA)
    tempB = mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3]
    print(tempB)
    # only the first line does
    mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3] = tempA
    mat[limitesA[0]*3:(limitesA[0]*3)+3, limitesA[1]*3:(limitesA[1]*3)+3, limitesA[2]*3:(limitesA[2]*3)+3] = tempB     

limA=limites(idO)
limB=limites(idD)

mover(limA, limB)
```

I expect the output change the two cubes

```
mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3] = tempA
mat[limitesA[0]*3:(limitesA[0]*3)+3, limitesA[1]*3:(limitesA[1]*3)+3, limitesA[2]*3:(limitesA[2]*3)+3] = tempB
```

but the actual output change only first cube

```
mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3] = tempA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
tempB = mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3]
```

It creates a *view*, which means that if `mat` changes, so will `tempB`.

Later on, you assign to the part of `mat` which `tempB` is sliced from:

```
mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3] = tempA
```

Therefore, the following two are equivalent:

```
mat[limitesA[0]*3:(limitesA[0]*3)+3, limitesA[1]*3:(limitesA[1]*3)+3, limitesA[2]*3:(limitesA[2]*3)+3] = tempB

mat[limitesA[0]*3:(limitesA[0]*3)+3, limitesA[1]*3:(limitesA[1]*3)+3, limitesA[2]*3:(limitesA[2]*3)+3] = tempA
```

To fix this, make a copy:

```
tempB = mat[limitesB[0]*3:(limitesB[0]*3)+3, limitesB[1]*3:(limitesB[1]*3)+3, limitesB[2]*3:(limitesB[2]*3)+3].copy()
```

Comment: Ok. I already understood with your explanation. I think I can also use a deep copy, this would do the same. Thanks

Comment: @norboot You can, but it might be slower. If your array contains only `ints`/`floats`, then a shallow copy is fine.